# Import selected tables from RDBMS in sqoop

Tags: shell, sqoop, sqoop2

I am learning sqoop.

I want to import some selected tables from the database, how to do that?

If I have 1000 tables in single database, then I want to import only 500 tables.

I can use **--exclude-tables** , but I can't enter all 500 tables names in command line to exclude. Kindly suggest me, how to achieve it?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it by writing a shell script something like this.

```
#!/bin/sh

# You can list excluded table here or you can list it in some file and call 
# it here.
exclude_tables="tab1,tab2"

import-all-tables --connect jdbc:mysql://192.168.0.101/mysql -username test \ 
-P --warehouse-dir /home/user_all_tables --exclude-tables $exclude_tables -m 1


echo "Sqoop import completed."
exit 0
```

Comment: Thanku Sandeep, Is there any other way?

Comment: @DevPerson No other way directly from command prompt yet... Alternatively you can put it somewhere in a file and then you can read it again through file in shell script.